# Meaning of "Crises involving a tick."

Tags: meaning

Here is the place where I saw this: http://feltron.com/ar11_04.html (in the right-bottom corner of the first page).

Comment: What on Earth have you been reading?  This appears to be either the musings of a highly intelligent being, or the ramblings of a schizophrenic!

Comment: Here it is http://i.imgur.com/XW9swEf.png. Text is following: "Crises involving a tick. One. Spotted by Olga, removed by Mom."

Comment: See below, I've improved my answer.  Should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A tick is a small blood sucking arachnid.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick)

Crises is the plural of [crisis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisis).  As they are listing countable items, they are using crises instead of crisis.  This is a bit confusing since there is only one item on the list.

In essence she could make a list like so:

> Crises involving ticks: 1
>   Crises involving monkeys: 0
>   Crises involving bees: 32

The crisis involving a tick is described as Olga found one attached to her and her mother removed it.

It is a use of hyperbole, as the finding of a tick attached to you would never be considered an actual crisis.  But, rather, this person was highly distressed at having a small parasite attached to them.